# Securely storing the string used to generate a symmetric encryption key

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a windows forms applciation that stores encrypted files to disk. At runtime, it decrypts those files and passes the resulting memorystreams to Datasets. I am using symmetric encryption with AESManaged.

There are custom functions to generate Key and IV byte arrays from a string. However I am currently hard coding the secure string that I use to generate Key and Iv, which I think defeats the purpose of encryption. I understand that the best way would be to prompt the user for a password and use that string. Is there any other way around this where I don't have to prompt the user for a password? Also I cannot use DPAPI because the encrypted data file is expected to be shared between users and computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to have your cake and eat it too :) You cannot store decryption key and use it, and not have it recoverable by someone. Only thing you could do is not make it obvious where it is by obfuscating your code, preencrypting your key and decrypting it dynamically, maybe through several rounds of decryption scattered around several classes. Unlike rest of programming disciplines, this is where messy code is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should still consider DPAPI; not for encrypting the data files, but for encrypting the secret string.

Would it be possible to ask your user just one time to enter the secret string?*  If you could, you would then:

- Use DPAPI to encrypt it
- Then store the encrypted value somewhere (config file, settings file, registry, wherever you like.  Preferably something secured to the user, not general public.)
- Then when you need it, use DPAPI to retrieve the secret string
- Use the rest of your code as you already have it.

Since your data files will still be encrypted by AES with the same secret string they will still be interchangeable. (Among people with the same secret string...so now you've just made it so your app can have multiple secure groups, with each group setting their own secret...but that's a tangent.)

The advantage is that even if someone gets your code, no amount of reverse engineering is going to give back the secret string..because it's not there.

Note that this is better than obfuscation alone.  With obfuscation, if the attacker gets your code and can run it in their own environment, they can attach a debugger and just stop at the point you pass the string to the AES code.  They don't have to care how many tricks you use to scramble it.  They just watch it after you've unscrambled it.  With DPAPI this won't work unless they're running your code in the user's context...in which case, game over anyway.

I'm not saying DPAPI is perfect, but in this case I would really consider it before resorting to obfuscation alone.  (You could still run your code through an obfuscation tool: also a good thing, just not enough.)

*If not, can you supply it at install/initial config time?  I've seen some where it installs with the secret key in plain text in a file, then the program encrypts it on first use.